# Remove characters from column 'n' until end-line

Tags: sed

I have a huge text file. This file has many lines and most of them have more that `N` characters before end-line.

How can I use `sed` to truncate lines from `N`*th* character until the end of line?

*Note: Obviously after this operation maximum line length is `N`.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With sed you can do it like this:

```
sed 's/\(.\{1,80\}\).*/\1/'
```

To truncate to 80 columns. It's more readable with ERE (Extended Regular Expressions), enabled with `-r` in GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.{1,80}).*/\1/'
```

But, you could do it more efficiently with cut:

```
cut -c 1-80
```